# is there any API like blockchain.info and bitcore with tutorial?

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcore

is there? I'm finding it hard for starters to look it up without tutorials via the net, blockchain.info tutorial(on youtube and a single one) seems to be good but getting API key on blockchain.info is pretty hard. meanwhile bitcore has nothing but a 48-hour reply community. is there an API with a tutorial while they have an active community? TIA

Answer (score 2):

Check out 21. There are some [bitcoin tutorials](https://21.co/learn/) as well as a [developer community](https://slack.21.co/).

Answer (score 2):

Bitcore has excellent documentation and examples... It sound like you are familiar with their forums but maybe not their developer site?

- Get Started: https://bitcore.io/start
- Guides and Tutorials: https://bitcore.io/guides
- API Docs: https://bitcore.io/api